# How can I create onedir file from .spec file using pyinstaller?

Tags: pyinstaller

I want to make onedir file using pyinstaller, but I have got ready .spec file and if I type:

```
pyinstaller -onedir filename.spec
```

It does not make a onedir file but onefile.
The question is if I can add somewhere in .spec file a line that will change it to onedir?
Here is the content of my spec file:

```
    # -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-

from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import collect_data_files
datas = collect_data_files("scipy.special")
block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['main_gui.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Users\\User\\OneDrive\\Pulpit\\BulaniPunchWydanie\\main'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=['scipy.special._ufuncs_cxx',
                            'scipy.linalg.cython_blas',
                            'scipy.linalg.cython_lapack',
                            'scipy.integrate',
                            'scipy.integrate.quadrature',
                            'scipy.integrate.odepack',
                            'scipy.integrate._odepack',
                            'scipy.integrate.quadpack',
                            'scipy.integrate._quadpack',
                            'scipy.integrate._ode',
                            'scipy.integrate.vode',
                            'scipy.integrate._dop',
                            'scipy.integrate.lsoda'
                'scipy.special.__init__'],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=['matplotlib',
            'matplotlib.backends',
            'PIL'],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          [],
          name='Bulani Punch',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          upx_exclude=[],
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=False , icon='Punch_Logo.ico')
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, nevermind - I have found the solution.

This part of code in spec file :

```
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          [],
          name='Bulani Punch',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          upx_exclude=[],
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=False , icon='Punch_Logo.ico')
```

Has to be replaced by that:

```
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          [],
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='Bulani Punch',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=False , icon='Punch_Logo.ico')
coll = COLLECT(exe,
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               strip=False,
               upx=True,
               upx_exclude=[],
               name='Bulani Punch')
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: I've just generated new .spec file using pyinstaller -onedir function on my .py file and check out the differences between this version and onefile version of spec file.
The only 2 lines that may varry in such case are icon and name, anyone can replace it by theirs